# Нужно ли изучать Blueprint , чтобы писать на c++ в UE4?

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, unreal-engine-4

Я начинающий программист , который изучает c++. Хочу уйти в сферу game development. Долго выбирал движок, и выбрал Unreal Engine 4.

Нужно ли изучать blueprint прежде чем  начинать писать на c++  или же  можно обойтись без него?

Comment: Скорее все надо делать наоборот. Сначала начать писать на С++, потом заняться выбором движка и уж потом ковырять blueprint, если они понадобятся.